# How to reconnect InfoPath task form to SPD workflow after moving it to the new Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-2010, migration, sharepoint-designer, infopath2010

I have Globally reusable workflow (created in SPD) in my test site collection. This WF uses custom InfoPath task form. Now I am trying to move it to the new production site collection. I've done next steps.

1. Copy my globally reusable WF (in SPD) to make it reusable (I can't save GLOBALLY reusable WF as a template).
2. Save new reusable WF (not globally reusable) as WF template and deployed it to the production environment.

And now my WF is working well, but I've missed my custom InfoPath task forms and I don't know how to connect it to my WF.

**Is there any way to reuse InfoPath task forms from my workflow after moving from test environment to production? May be I have to use another approach?**

Every suggestions are very appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

PS: I don't understand completely what is happenning behind the scenes, when I am creating custom InfoPath task forms in SPD. I googled about it, but couldn't find any good article to clarify. If you know any articles or books which could help me in my understanding of relationship between InfoPath and SharePoint 2010, it would be great if you recommend it.

PPS: SharePoint 2010.

**UPDATE 1:** It seems like InfoPath forms are missed in step 1 (I can't see forms in wsp file). If I create new reusable WF (not globally) with InfoPath forms, I can see them in the wsp file and WF deploys correctly with forms. 
It seems like the [way which Microsoft recommends for converting Globaly reusable WF to reusable WF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff358272.aspx) doesn't work well and miss InfoPath task forms.

Also I found an [unanswered question about the same problem](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/5be39312-88ea-4f1b-ab5b-d2c1cce965ca/) on MSDN forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gennady Vanin, who helped me to find [a solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/how-to-reconnect-infopath-task-form-to-spd-workflow-after-moving-it-to-the-new-s/41551#41551).

To reconnect InfoPath form we can use the next approach:

**1. Export source files of the form.**
Open form in InfoPath designer. And because we can't republish it to the different place using wizard (its type is a Workflow form), we should Export source files (from the menu File\Publish) to some folder. 
After this step we received a set of files, one of which is "manifest.xsf".

**2. Close InfoPath designer.**

**3. Correct URLs in manifest.xsf** 
Open "manifest.xsf" in a text editor. Find all URL related to the first site collection and replace it with new URLs linked to new site collection. Save the file.
**Hint:** If you don't know the URL to publish in new site collection, you can open autogenerated form from it in the same manner (look at URLs in its manifest.xsf).

**4. Publish changed form.**
Open InfoPath designer, open corrected manifest.xsf in it and publish it (by pressing the publish button for example).

**5. Hurray! The form is deployed to the new place!**

You should repeat this steps for all custom InfoPath task forms in your workflow.

If somebody needs more detailed description, I could add screenshots.